# Django debug toolbar 404 with wagtail

Tags: django, debugging, wagtail, django-debug-toolbar

I am trying to get `django-debug-toolbar` working. I have followed the [installation steps](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) and I get the sidebar including stats (e.g. SQL 1 query in 2.75ms, Static Files 19 Files used, 30 receivers of 12 signals)  which seem to be legitimate and indicate that its working.

However, when I click for more info on a given tab, I get a 404 in browser, and this sort of thing in the console:

```
"GET /__debug__/render_panel/?store_id=ac74875cfe864b2dab4c6d17c1d1ed5d&panel_id=RequestPanel HTTP/1.1" 404 1791"
```

Other pages on site do work.

I have tried various configurations in `urls.py`. Here is what I currently have:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.wagtailadmin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.wagtailcore import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.wagtaildocs import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),

    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    url(r'^pages/', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
import debug_toolbar
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


    # Serve static and media files from development server
    # urlpatterns = [
    #     url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    # ]
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have tried a few other configurations here, including having:

```
import debug_toolbar
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

in the `if settings.DEBUG:` block.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comment says, the wagtail urls must be the last pattern.

One option would be to move the debug toolbar urls to the beginning of the list:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Or you could remove the wagtail urls from there current position, and add them after your `if settings.DEBUG:` block.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

I’ve included the debug toolbar urls inside and `if settings.DEBUG:` block here because that’s what the docs recommend, but that’s not the reason why it works. The key is to make sure that the wagtail urls come at the very end.